# How do I troubleshoot automatic reload using VitePWA?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, vite, vite-plugin-pwa

I am trying to leverage vite to automatically have the browser reload my PWA application when I push an update (I used the instructions [here](https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/auto-update.html)).

I added this to my vite.config.js file:

```
VitePWA({
  registerType: 'autoUpdate'
})
```

I also added this code to my index.jsx file:

```
import { registerSW } from 'virtual:pwa-register'

registerSW({ immediate: true })
```

The problem is that when I push an update (using firebase deploy), the client does not get the latest changes unless I refresh the page. I am trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this, so here are some questions:

1. Are the changes I made sufficient for auto-reload?
2. Do I need to update my package.json version number for the auto-reload to take effect?
3. Do I need a custom service worker file, or will the auto-generated one suffice?
4. Can I inspect any of the generated files (sw, workbox, etc.) to see if the proper code has been added?
5. Can I use chrome dev tools somehow to troubleshoot?
6. Is there somewhere I can add logs to help troubleshoot?

Comment: @Lynchy Just posted a solution that worked for me, incase you still need it

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue too. I added the same code you did, had to add this to my `tsconfig.json` to fix a build error as well:

```
"types": [
  "vite-plugin-pwa/client"
]
```

In addition to your code, I added these meta tags in my `index.html` to disable the browser cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Finally, in my case I'm deploying my app to Cloudflare Pages, so I followed these instructions to setup a page rule that bypasses the cache: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/how-to/edge-browser-cache-ttl/create-page-rules/#cache-everything

In my testing, it gets triggered by a page load or refresh, then wait a few seconds for it to download the new files, then it will force-refresh.